# Can anyone explain the second reduction rule for ZF-expressions?

Tags: haskell

`[ e | v <- f:fs, q ]` reduces to `[ e | q ] [ v := f ] ++ [ e | v <- fs, q ]`

The output of `[ e | v <- f:fs, q ]` should be a single list. What does it mean to put two lists together in the reduction? I mean you can't just put two lists together like this `["a"]["b"]`.

Also, is the symbol `:=` the same as `=`?

Comment: Where did you see the first line you are quoting? Please provide more context.

Comment: From the notation after "reduces to" it appears to be in some meta language. It isn't Haskell, so don't apply the same rules to it.

Comment: I googled "ZF expressions" and found the article the OP is quoting from: http://www.cantab.net/users/antoni.diller/haskell/units/unit04.html (see ZF2 in the reduction rules)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more context. I have the other 4 rules, but they won't help. For example, rule number 1, `[ e | v <- [], q ]` reduces to `[]`, where `q` is a sequence of zero or more qualifiers.

Comment: Assuming that you are quoting from the page @4castle linked to, an explanation can be found in the part of the rule you haven't quoted here: "where `h [ v := f ]` represents [...]".

Comment: I found it in some pdf file and it doesn't have such explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you mention is not Haskell code, but a meta-notation for *substitution* which is frequently used in programming languages theory.

If `e` and `t` are Haskell expressions, and `x` is a Haskell variable, we write `e [x := t]` to denote the expression `e` where all the free occurrences of `x` have been replaced with `t` (and avoiding captures). For example

```
x [x := t]                       ===> t
x+3 [x := t]                     ===> t+3
f x + (\x -> x + 32) x [x := t]  ===> f t + (\x -> x + 32) t
[ f x y | y <- [1..x] ] [x := t] ===> [ f t y | y <- [1..t] ]
```

Again, this is not a Haskell operator, but a "mathematical" meta-level operator which takes as input Haskell code (syntax) and produces as output Haskell code (syntax).

It is usually exploited to define beta reduction on lambdas:

```
(\x -> e) t ---beta---> e [x := t]
```

Anyway, in the posted expression

```
[ e | q ] [ v := f ] ++ [ e | v <- fs, q ]
```

the first `[...]` and the last are Haskell list comprehensions, while `[v := f]` is the meta-notation for substitution. For instance, here's a fully evaluated example

```
[ f x y | x <- 1:2:[] , y <- [0..x] ]
===> definition of list comprehension
[ f x y | y <- [0..x] ] [x := 1] ++ [ f x y | x <- 2:[] , y <- [0..x] ]
===> substitution
[ f 1 y | y <- [0..1] ] ++ [ f x y | x <- 2:[] , y <- [0..x] ]
===> definition of list comprehension
[ f 1 y | y <- [0..1] ] 
      ++ [ f x y | y <- [0..x] ] [x := 2] 
      ++ [ f x y | x <- [] , y <- [0..x] ]
===> substitution
[ f 1 y | y <- [0..1] ] ++ [ f 2 y | y <- [0..2] ] ++ [ f x y | x <- [] , y <- [0..x] ]
===> definition of list comprehension
[ f 1 y | y <- [0..1] ] ++ [ f 2 y | y <- [0..2] ] ++ []
===> many other steps here
[ f 1 0, f 1 1 ] ++ [ f 2 0, f 2 1, f 2 2 ] ++ []
===> concatenation
[ f 1 0, f 1 1, f 2 0, f 2 1, f 2 2 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing where you've seen this it's hard to know for certain what is meant.
`[e | q][v := f]` is *not* valid Haskell code (barring some creative use of language extensions).

What is probably meant is something more like

```
[e' | q'] ++ [e | v <- fs, q]
```

where `e'` is `e` with all instances of `v` in replaced with `f`, and `q'` is `q` with all instances of `v` replaced with `f`

So, for example if `f` was 5, `e` was `v*2` and `q` was `odd v` we'd have

```
[v*2 | v <- 5:fs, odd v]
```

Which would reduce to

```
[5*2|odd 5] ++ [v*2 | v <- fs, odd v]
```

Since `odd 5` reduces to `True` we end up with

```
[5*2] ++ [v*2 | f<- fs, odd v]
```

Comment: I think I know what it means now.  Does `[ e | v <- f:fs, q ]` reduces to `[e | v = f || v <- fs, q]` make sense?

Comment: @user8314628 Doesn't make sense to me. What's a double pipe supposed to mean?

Comment: `||` means or in Haskell?

Comment: @user8314628 yes, `||` means "or", and no, `[e | v = f || v <- fs, q]` does not make any sense and is not Valid Haskell (I can't even guess the intent of it). the answer gives you the translation: `[ e | v <- (f:fs), q ]` => `[let v = f in e | let v = f in q] ++ [e | v <- fs, q ]`.